# ActiveRecord primary key is a varchar, error when saving

Tags: sql-server, ruby, activerecord

I have an active record class

```
  class Service_Catalogue < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name  "service_catalogue"
    set_primary_key "myKey"
  end
```

myKey is an nvarchar (sql server).

When I try and save it

```
  service_catalogue= Service_Catalogue.new()
  service_catalogue.myKey = "somevalue"
  service_catalogue.save
```

I get the following error:

```
  IDENTITY_INSERT could not be turned OFF for table [service_catalogue] (ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError)
```

It seems like ActiveRecord thinks that the primary key is an identity column (it's not its a varchar) and so is failing.

Is there a way to tell it not to try and turn off identity insert?

**UPDATE**

It turns out the version of the active record sql server adapter was to blame.
I had previously been using 1.0.0.9250 but somehow 2.2.19 got installed (I presume when doing a gem update). After reverting to the old version it works fine.

Comment: yeah, its a rubbish design but that is the way it has to be :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular problem I was experiencing was caused because of an inadvertent gem upgrade (thankfully using bundler now this does not happen!).

The old active record sql server adapter (1.0.0.9250) supports what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

ActiveRecord likes to have integer ID columns and throws a fit if this is not the case. It can be coached to deal with alternatives, but this depends on your environment.

An alternative is to have a conventional integer-based ID field, and  a unique "key" field that is used for lookups.

```
class Service_Catalogue < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name  "service_catalogue"

  validates_uniqueness_of :myKey
end
```

If it's possible, it might be more convenient to alter your schema to fit ActiveRecord than to coach ActiveRecord to deal with your schema. If not, you might need to really get down and dirty.

Another approach could be to use an alternative ORM like DataMapper which does not have the same limitations.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. unfortunately this is a system that I cannot change and have to use AR on.
I found the solution anyway and have updated the answer with it.